# Can I move all wordpress images in only one folder?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a wordpress website with several thousand images and these images need to be replaced. The images are currently all organized in different folders with mm/yyyy. So the standard wordpress folder structure. The images are stored on AWS S3 bucket. Is it possible to move all the current images into one big folder to make it easier to replace them?

The website should continue to run normally while the images are being replaced.

Comment: It's difficult with the existing/current images/media files as file paths are stored in DB and might be used in posts/pages as well.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you just need to set the path for the images in the PHP template file. you can use function like get_site_url() plus directory of your image folder on the server.

get_site_url() function retrieves the URL for a given site.

This link can prove more info on how to do it:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).